# pkgdown error: Undefined tag in usage tag_code

Tags: r, web, devtools, pkgdown

I'm running into an error message that I do not understand when trying to build a website for my package with pkgdown.

As the instruction (https://pkgdown.r-lib.org/) says:

I've run `usethis::use_pkgdown()` one time.

When I run `pkgdown::build_site()` nothing happens and then I get the error message *Undefined tag in usage tag_code* .

Googling the error message did not help and I have no idea where to start looking for errors in my package. Does anybody know what to do in that case? Documenting with `devtools::document()` works fine and so does `devtools::load_all()`.

I don't really know how to make a reprex out of that so if you need any more information I'm happy to provide it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem:

I mistakenly used the tag @usage in the description of a function. This did not lead to an error in `devtools::document()` but apparently `pkgdown::build_site()` could not handle it.